# modal dialog is not displaying in ctabview in yii

Tags: jquery, yii

I am dealing with the concept of ctabview .

And in  one of tab  I wanna popup a modal dialog when user clicks a anchor tag.

But I didnt get the dialog and had error `(..).dialog is not a function.`

After long search on these I have understand that the Jquery's that I used

for ctabview and modal dialog are conflicting.

in my `config/main.php`

I had following jquery scripts

```
<?php  
  $baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
  $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
  $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/jquery-min.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
  $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/jquery-ui.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
  $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/jquery-ui.min.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
  $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/jquery-active.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);


  $cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl.'/css/jquery-ui.css');
?>
```

and I had used also `$.noConflict(true);` but no use.

how to overcome this to show modal popup in one of tabs in ctabview .

please anyone help me stuck in this topic for 2 days.

thanks in advance..

Comment: have you check that the jquery-ui is add in the page?

Comment: yes it works after adding jquery-ui to my page....thank you harsh for reply.

Comment: I had list of anchor tags so i had used pagination for that list..now in one of tabs i had anchor tags list with pagination..modal popup is working for the first page of anchors tags in tab..but not for the next pages why

Comment: can you please check that what is the error in the next page?

Comment: I didnt get any error on page or on console..but when i click on anchor tag on second page...redirecting to the popup page rather than displaying the page on modal popup

Comment: can you give me that link of that page?

Comment: No thanks,,I had just set pagination to false for my gridview in tab and works fine...thank you for response